# get the video duration for multiple file uploads in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the duration of multiple videos when the user uploads multiple videos

I got some code from answers here and modified them but I can't make them work as intended

I use this HTML code

```
<div id="input-upload-file" class="box-shadow">
  <span>- Try Upload -</span> 
  <input type="file" class="upload" id="fileUp" name="fileUpload" multiple onchange="setFileInfo(this.files)">
</div>
<div id="infos"></div>
```

and this javascript code

```
const formatSeconds = seconds => new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);

let myVideos = [];
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
function setFileInfo(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    myVideos.push(files[i]);
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.preload = 'metadata';
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
    video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)
      var duration = video.duration;
      myVideos[i].duration = duration;
      updateInfos();
    }}
    ;
  }

function updateInfos(deleteName) {
  let info = document.querySelector('#infos');
  info.innerHTML="";
  let total = 0;
  for (let j = myVideos.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    let v = myVideos[j];
    if (deleteName === myVideos[j].name) {
      myVideos.splice(j, 1);
    } else {
      info.innerHTML += "<div class='row' data-name='" + v.name + "'>" + 
                            "<div class='close' onclick=remove(this)>&times</div>" +
                             v.name + ", duration: " + formatSeconds(v.duration) + 
                        "</div>";
      total += myVideos[i].duration;
    }
  }
  if (myVideos.length)
    info.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>Total: " + formatSeconds(total) + '</div>';
}

function remove(e) {
    updateInfos(e.parentNode.dataset.name);
}
```

Comment: Hi Omar and welcome to SO. What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: If I select multiple videos nothing is returned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and fixed several issues:

1. The `function` that you attach to `video.onloadedmetadata` is using `i`, but *not* with the value of `i` that you may be expecting. By the time the function runs, `i` will be equal to `files.length` because *the for-loop that controls `i` has already ended*. In such a situation it is best to make a local copy of the loop variable, and use that in the inner function. **However...** we shouldn't actually be using `i`, we should be using the *index of the current item of `myVideos`*, which is defined by `myVideos.length - 1`.
2. The function `updateInfos` uses `j` as a loop variable, but at one point it was using `i` instead. I changed that to `total += myVideos[j].duration;`.
3. Not all videos can be read accurately, and then `duration` becomes `undefined`. I changed `formatSeconds` to be resilient for that. Of course the sum-of-durations will then also fail and it will show `NaN`. I have no idea if there is a way around the problem of `duration` not being available, that is not my expertise.

Working version:

```js
const formatSeconds = seconds => seconds >= 0
  ? new Date(seconds * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)
  : "?... " + seconds;

let myVideos = [];
//window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function setFileInfo(files) {
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    myVideos.push(files[i]);
    let video = document.createElement('video');
    video.preload = 'metadata';
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
    let index = myVideos.length - 1;
    video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)
      myVideos[index].duration = video.duration;
      updateInfos();
    }}
    ;
  }

function updateInfos(deleteName) {
  let info = document.querySelector('#infos');
  info.innerHTML="";
  let total = 0;
  for (let j = myVideos.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    let v = myVideos[j];
    if (deleteName === myVideos[j].name) {
      myVideos.splice(j, 1);
    } else {
      info.innerHTML += "<div class='row' data-name='" + v.name + "'>" + 
                            "<div class='close' onclick=remove(this)>&times</div>" +
                             v.name + ", duration: " + formatSeconds(v.duration) + 
                        "</div>";
      total += myVideos[j].duration;
    }
  }
  if (myVideos.length)
    info.innerHTML += "<div class='row'>Total: " + formatSeconds(total) + '</div>';
}

function remove(e) {
    updateInfos(e.parentNode.dataset.name);
}
```

```css
#infos {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  background: #eee
}
```

```html
<div id="input-upload-file" class="box-shadow">
  <span>- Try Upload -</span> 
  <input type="file" class="upload" id="fileUp" name="fileUpload" multiple onchange="setFileInfo(this.files)">
</div>
<br />
Infos:
<div id="infos"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer code has come a long way into the solution, butif I select multiple videos it does not show the duration of the videos other than the first, is there a fix? I also will try working with it

Comment: On 2nd thought, we shouldn't be using `i`, we should be using the index of the last item in the array, defined by `let index = myVideos.length - 1;`. Answer updated.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, the code now functions like I wanted.